# Understanding C# compilation error with ternary operator

Tags: c#, inheritance, if-statement, ternary-operator

I have copied the following code from `Wrox Professional ASP.NET 4.0 MVC 4` book, page 179 (Chapter "Understanding the Security Vectors in a Web Application") with the little modification of making it `protected` and storing as utility method in my abstract application-wide `Controller`

```
protected ActionResult RedirectToLocal(string returnUrl)
{
    if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl))
    {
        return Redirect(returnUrl);
    }
    else
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
}
```

The code above is aimed at securing the MVC application from open redirection attacks, which are not subject of the question.

The code is obviously well-formed, compiles and I trust it works.

The problem arises when "smartly" changing the code above into the following one-liner

```
return (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl)) ? Redirect(returnUrl) : RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
```

The one-liner above is supposed to do exactly the same as the extended code (no, ReSharper didn't suggest me to replace, it was my initiative).

The compilation error is the following: `there is no implicit conversion between System.Web.Mvc.RedirectResult and System.Web.Mvc.RedirectToRouteResult`.

ReSharper then comes to help and suggests the following modification

```
return (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl)) ? (ActionResult) Redirect(returnUrl) : RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
```

#### The question is "why do I have to cast Redirect method"?

Since both `Redirect` and `RedirectToAction` return a subclass of `ActionResult` (verified via F12) and that subclass is the return value of the function, it should be automatically compatible. Or at least, in my knowledge of C#, either both codes compile or they both don't.

To be more general, the question could be reformulated as follows:

Suppose I have class A, B and C

```
abstract class A {}
class B: A{}
class C: A{}
```

And suppose the following function works

```
private A Function(){
    if (condition) return new B();
    else return new C();
}
```

Why the following one-liner doesn't compile?

```
private A Function(){
    return (condition) ? new B(): new C();
}
```

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2006/05/24/type-inference-woes-part-one.aspx

Comment: So type inference on the conditional operator is broken?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It doesn't compile because the compiler decides what the return-type of the one-liner is based upon one of the two return-values. Since type B doesn't derive of type C, or the other way around, the two types are not mutually exclusive, and the return type of the if (as a whole) cannot be derived that way.

If you would want to do it in a one-liner, you have to cast the return-values to the type that you want to return, which is type A.

```
private A Function(){
    return (condition) ? ((A)new B()): ((A)new C());
}
```

UPDATE: I didn't see that you already do the casting in your question, my apologies.

Comment: Additional explanation (for posterity): in order to verify that the one-liner's expression is compatible with the return statement, the compiler must match the type returned by the one-liner with the function declaration. It starts to examine the ternary operator to determine the type returned by them. Even if both B and C extend A and even if anything extends object in C#, the compiler is unable to make a concrete decision if no implicit cast exists or no explicit casts are put in the code

Comment: So the extended code works because "return C" expression is compatible with "protected A" and "return B" too. But in case of the ternary expression, the compiler simply doesn't do the effort of climbing back the inheritance tree of B and C to find the common ancestor (which is return-compatible). This is by design to make the compiler efficient and simple to maintain: the compiler must directly determine the type returned by that ternary operator, seen as an atomic expression

Comment: Superb additional explanation, @djechelon

Answer (score 2):

The compiler expects the same return type in a conditional statement, so it expects both of these to be the same type.  If you cast the options to ActionResult, it will work.  You may be able to get along with the compiler by only casting the last one.

```
return (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl)) ? (ActionResult)Redirect(returnUrl) : (ActionResult)RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
```

Comment: +1 as i was reading the original question I guessed this was going to be the punch line. theoretically c# could allow it to work but it would only work in some cases and would hence be confusing (I assume c++ ?: is the same).