# Conditional operator type inference

Tags: c#, type-inference, conditional-operator

Why can't the c# compiler infer the type of the conditional expression in the code below?

```
class A {}
class B : A {}
class C : A {}

A TestInference ()
{
    return new Random ().Next () == 0 ? new B () : new C ();
}
```

EDIT: I know how to fix the compiler error (just cast the `B` or the `C` to `A`), my question is: why can't the compiler understand that the type is `A` by itself?

Comment: Check out http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2006/05/24/type-inference-woes-part-one.aspx , mentioned in this SO discussion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14144131/understanding-c-sharp-compilation-error-with-ternary-operator

Comment: @Steve thank you. I'll mark this as duplicate of the one you linked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the docs:

> Either the type of first_expression and second_expression must be the same, or an
>   implicit conversion must exist from one type to the other.

In your case there is no implicit conversion, but if you would cast one of them to `A` it should work.

But yeah, one could argue that it should be able to figure it out itself, but there are actually some good reasons for it not doing that, as explained in the first of the links Steve posted.

Consider the following case:

```
interface D {}
class A {}
class B : A, D {}
class C : A, D {}

var x = condition ? new B() : new C();
```

Should the compiler make `x` an `A`, or a `D`?

Comment: Yeah, that was my point...

Comment: Guess the answer would be that it's a design decision by the C# team then.

Comment: " there are actually some good reasons for it not doing that, as explained in the first of the links Steve posted" -- no, there are no good reasons, and none are discussed there. The only reason given is "We do not want to get into the business ...". Other languages, such as Scala, do much more extensive type inference with no problem.

Comment: I disagree. `B` and `C` in this case inherit from `A`. But what if they both also implemented an interface `IInterface`. Should the compiler make the operator return an `A`, or an `IInterface`?