# Instanciating with a ternary operator

Tags: c#, inheritance, ternary-operator

Let us consider the following classes:

```
public interface A {}
public class B:A {}
public class C:A {}
```

I wanted to create an instance of either B or C in one line with a ternary operator:

```
A a = condition? new B() : new C();
```

This line doesn't compile (no implicit conversion), but casting either `B` or `C` with `(A)` solves the problem.

While this is an easy workaround, I want to understand why that is. Is this a quirk of the language or is there a clear reason for this statement not to be valid?

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14144131/understanding-c-sharp-compilation-error-with-ternary-operator