# Check for null before referencing joining table fails

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have a `User` table, which may have a related (FK) record in `Address`.

So in `LINQ`, I am trying to:

```
var data = _context.User.Where(x=>x.Deleted.HasValue == false)
  .Select(y=> new MyObject {
      Id = y.Id,
      Name = y.Name,
      Address = y.Address != null ? y.Address.Description : null
  });
```

But as soon as I add the ternary operator (As I cannot reference `y.Address.Description` if there is no record there), my `Select` fails with a design-time error: `Ambiguous Invocation`.

What's the correct way to do this? In this case, there may be no 'Address' record.

Design time error on the 'select':
[image]

Comment: Paste the "*actual*" exception and stack trace

Comment: 'design-time error: Ambiguous Invocation.' --- do you mean compile time error?

Comment: No. Design time. This is being shown by the UI before I even compile, as soon as I add the turnary.

Comment: in which ui, i'm corious. does linq depend on some ui?

Comment: I use Rider. The issue seemed to be the casting was required as per the accepted answer.

Comment: Questions like this need more details. It's important to know what `_context.User` is, *exactly*. I.e. also including EF version. It looks like it's a `DbSet` which would mean that you don't need this null check at all, just `Address = y.Address.Description` will be perfectly fine, irrespective of what an IDE is telling you at design time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to cast the null to a string:

```
var data = _context.User.Where(x=>x.Deleted.HasValue == false)
  .Select(y=> new MyObject {
      Id = y.Id,
      Name = y.Name,
      Address = y.Address != null ? y.Address.Description : (string) null
  });
```

I assume here that Description is of type string.

You could also try the Null-conditional operator:

```
var data = _context.User.Where(x=>x.Deleted.HasValue == false)
  .Select(y=> new MyObject {
      Id = y.Id,
      Name = y.Name,
      Address = y.Address?.Description
  });
```

The problem has to do with type inference. The compiler cannot determine the result type of the ternary operator, thus it is necessary to explicitly indicate the type of the third operand (the null) by casting it.

See related question: [Understanding C# compilation error with ternary operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14144131/understanding-c-sharp-compilation-error-with-ternary-operator)

Simple example to cause this error:

```
int? i = true ? 1 : null;
```

On Visual Studio 2019 / .Net Framework 4.7.2, I get the following error:

```
Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between 'int' and '<null>'
```

Correction:

```
int? i = true ? 1 : (int?) null;
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks! That is it. I have no idea why that happens. But it worked.

Comment: @Tarik, besides solve the issue, can you explain why the error, and provide minimal code to cuase that error(maybe not related to linq)?

Comment: @LeiYang Added explanations.

Comment: can you give **minimal code** in simple c# console app that cause `Ambiguous Invocation` exception?

Comment: @LeiYang Added an example as suggested.

Comment: i can compile and run this statement without any error `int? i = true ? 1 : null;`, vs2019, .net 5

Comment: @LeiYang Added error message along with platform. .Net 5 might be me smarter in inferring the resultant data type.

Comment: the exception is not `Ambiguous Invocation`, though